# Serialize a List of my class to Windows Phone Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm using the .net XmlSerializer class to serialize the state of my game into isolated storage.
This allows me to avoid mucking up my code with an immense number of attributes.

**I get an exception whenever I try to serialize a list of my structs of public data:**
  "circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type GameState_test.Planet"

**How do I fix this?** I've researched a ton of answers but none pertain to WP7.

```
public class Hazard { public Planet CurrentPlanet;} //reference to the planet its on

public struct Inventory
{
    public Inventory(int coins = 0, int arrows = 0) { Coins = coins; Arrows = arrows; }

    public int Coins;
    public int Arrows;
}

public class Planet
    {
        public Inventory Inventory;
        internal readonly int Index;              
        internal readonly List<int> Connections;  
        public Hazard pHazard; //hazard currently on planet
    }
```

Comment: What exception, **exactly** etc? (also, but minor: how do attributes that support an intended purpose of a class (serialization of a DTO) "muck up" the code?)

Comment: It was an invalidOperationException, and I don't have a separate class with the sole purpose of serialization.

Comment: Please post the whole exception message, including the inner exception.

Comment: @Griffin and what did the Message say? And what did the Message of the InnerException say? All the way down the tree to the first null InnerException. XmlSerializer is actually pretty good at telling you what is wrong, but only if you look

Comment: @Griffin it doesn't matter that serialization isn't it's sole purpose: you are using it for serialization: that's enough to make serialization attributes reasonable.

Comment: @MarcGravell : I was not aware of inner exceptions! Here it is:  "circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type GameState_test.Planet" No message in the outer exception. I posted 'Planet' code above.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez How do I prevent circular reference?

Comment: @Griffin use another type of serializer or use the XmlIgnore attribute on the Hazard.Planet.  See [this post](http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/c-parentchild-relationship-and-xml-serialization/)

Comment: Indeed; circular here often means parent/child - XmlIgnore can typically fx this, but we need to see an example. Other serializers may alsobe an option (protobuf-net can support references, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Serializer you are using does not support serializing circular references. Switch to the DataContract Serializer (System.Runtime.Serialization) and follow this guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/03/26/561188.aspx
or use a thrid party serializer that supports it.